# WPEngine and Duplicator plugin

Tags: wordpress, web-deployment

I am a front end developer/designer and I am new in managing dev teams so please tolerate my ignorance if possible. We use WPEngine for our website. There are two versions of it, LIVE and STAGING, latter is for testing and LIVE is the production site. We use Bitbucket to keep our code up to date and Azure for testing environments for the developers and designers. The developers work on their respective Bitbucket branches and then the code is merged (by doing a file comparison) with the "master" branch and then to STAGING and then LIVE.

Now, the most important tool here other than WPEngine itself, is the "DUPLICATOR" plugin by "Life in the grid" which is used to duplicate staging and is then deployed to testing environments. It is the fastest way to duplicate a Wordpress website I have found to this day. No editing required on wp-config.php, no change in settings in Wordpress dashboard etc. But lately, WPEngine times out the DUPLICATOR every single time I try to create a package and our process has since been broken as I have to push the files from master manually and then push the db via ssh manually as well, which brings substantial delays and has decent amount of room for human error. I looked into another tool named ManageWP, but they have problems working with WPEngine, seems like quite a few solutions out there have same issues.

Can you guys please guide me to better our process in any way possible?

Answer (score 1):

The best tool that I routinely use for working with WordPress sites is [Migrate-DB-Pro by DeliciousBrains](https://deliciousbrains.com/wp-migrate-db-pro/).  But, unlike Duplicator and ManageWP, this isn't a cloning tool for the entire site, but it migrates your database from one environment to another one, which is often the most difficult step.

I thought that WPEngine had a clone tool as one of their features, but it's probably just for cloning to other environments on your WPEngine account.

Here's how a typical workflow goes for me when working on a new client website.

1. I setup a WordPress instance locally, using either Vagrant (using two tools on top of vagrant called VVV and VV) or DesktopServer from ServerPress.
2. Install MigrateDB Pro to my local instance.
3. Install MigrateDB Pro to my remote instance
4. Using FTP or SSH, clone all of the files in the remote instance down to the local instance.  Typically I just clone the wp-content/ directory, but that's because I try to make sure that the WP versions are the same version before cloning.  You could copy the entire WordPress directory, but I think that'll introduce more problems than cloning just the wp-content/ directory.
5. Run MigrateDB Pro on my local instance, using the "Pull" command.  Migrate DB Pro is pretty genius in that it uses a unique secure hash to connect your two instances together, you copy one hash from your production (or staging) site and paste that into your local site.  The plugin does the rest -- Migrate DB Pro will automatically fill in the fields and make corrections to the SQL database where necessary.
6. Usually you have to then log back in with new credentials (as your default credentials are replaced by the remote credentials).

This is a workflow that works for me, and because I'm just pulling or pushing the database using Migrate DB Pro, I very rarely run into any PHP memory limits, execution time limits, or anything else that may be out of my control.  Plus, most hosts usually don't have transfer limits for FTP, but do over HTTP, so transferring the static files up and down that way will usually prevent problems for the client.

You're right that many cloning tools for WordPress have trouble with services from WPEngine, MediaTemple dedicated WordPress, and other managed, personal WordPress services... Those services want you to use their tools and their software is configured to restrict you from using your own tools many times.

For what it's worth Migrate DB Pro is a premium plugin, but it has a free version that should work.  I've bought a developer license for it just because it's a critical part of my WordPress development workflow.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a plugin instead of the default WP Engine push staging <--> Live? No need for some additional plugin to plug things up esp if it's not working.
Oh, and the default WPE plugin will bypass the 60 sec timeout script completely and you can push from staging to live with/out the database or specific tables even.
This can be found in the WPE > staging of the WP Engine plugin.

Another note, if you aren't using their default staging site, you can always hit up their support as they can clone any site to any site on the platform using a different tool that they have access too.

Comment: You are correct. The plugin was unnecessary and we adopted git as our only tool to push code.